# Display a number with two decimals to the user without changing the original precise value [javascript]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, decimal, rounding

Say for example I the following decimal value:

> let myDecimal = 117.049701384;

I want to show the user 117.05 but without changing the original precise value above.

Basically what I want is to mimic Excel behaviour with decimals, where it displays a number with two decimals but holds all the decimals for math operations.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to keep the UI clean of huge decimals numbers, but also keeping the math operations that I have to perform as precise as possible. I guess I can duplicate variables but that sounds cumbersome and tedious.

Is that posible in Javascript?

I am using Javascript and VueJS 2.x in this App.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Of course, you can use method **toFixed()**.

For example:

```js
let myDecimal = 117.049701384;
console.log(myDecimal.toFixed(2)); // 117.05
```

Comment: I am aware of the method toFixed, but I just can't figured out how to display it to the user without changing the variable. I need all the decimals for all the math operations that are chained together. I am using VueJS.

Comment: I understand that you will be using this value inside a <template> in a SFC. Just show in the template the value with the toFixed() function, this does not modify the original value of the property.

Comment: Thanks, your insight gave me a solution.

Answer (score 1):

use this where you return the mydecimal value back for the ui

mydecimal.tofixed(2)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
document.querySelectorAll("span[data-value]")
  .forEach(span => span.textContent = (+span.dataset.value).toFixed(2)); // or the VUE equivalent
```

```html
<span data-value="117.049701384"></span><br/>
<span data-value="217.01384"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by design your variable should contain value that must not be changed in runtime, do not declare it with `let`, but use `const` instead. This will save you some time in future. Then just convert/format your constant as you wish while displaying it to user.

```js
// Your value
const myDecimal = 117.049701384

// Show rounded result to user
console.log(Math.round(myDecimal * 100) / 100);

// Your constant still constant, obviously
console.log(myDecimal)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want truncation with rounding then toFixed is the function
If you do not want rounding then you can always use regEx

```js
let newVarT = (117.049701384).toFixed(2)-0
let newVarR = (117.049701384+"").match(/([\d]+\.[\d]{0,2})/)[1]-0
console.log( "toFixed", newVarT, "RegEx", newVarR );
```

The ending `-0` converts back to a number

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used toFixed(2)-0 to display it directly to the user. This way it doesn't change the original value and I can still use it for the rest of the application math operations as precise as posible.